# How to dynamically add css class to a certain element?

Tags: angular

Suppose I have a list of objects and I want to change a certain object styling. I am utilizing **ngClass** and **click** event to toggle CSS class.

```
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item" [ngClass]="{'active': isClassVisible }" (click)="isClassVisible = !isClassVisible">1</li>
  <li class="item" [ngClass]="{'active': isClassVisible }" (click)="isClassVisible = !isClassVisible;">2</li>
  <li class="item" [ngClass]="{'active': isClassVisible }" (click)="isClassVisible = !isClassVisible;">3</li>
  <li class="item" [ngClass]="{'active': isClassVisible }" (click)="isClassVisible = !isClassVisible;">4</li>
</ul>
```

then in component I have

```
export class MyComponent {
  isClassVisible: false;
}
```

and CSS

```
.active {
  background: black;
}
```

However with this approach, when I click on an element inside list, the CSS class is applied to all of them, but not the element I clicked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not make a directive to handle it

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({ selector: '[myActive]' })
export class ActiveDirective {

    private _isActive = false;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {

    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this._isActive = !this._isActive;
        if (this._isActive) {
          this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'active');
        } else {
          this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'active');
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item" myActive>1</li>
  <li class="item" myActive>2</li>
</ul>
```

- The `Renderer` class has been marked as deprecated since Angular version 4 and  been completely removed since Angular version 9. You can use `Renderer2` in lower angular versions too. - [ref](https://angular.io/guide/migration-renderer)
- [Renderer2 Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

Comment: Thank you, mate. If I get it rright, usually directives are meant to be used to add behaviour to an DOM-element, whereas components require their own templates.

Comment: more cleaner way to do the same , +1

Answer (score 0):

because you are using same variable in all the `li's` and when you click one of them style is applying to all of them.

Try using diff diff variable on each li

or use like this

```
<ul class="container">
  <li *ngFor = 'let n of num' class="item" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedLi == n }" (click)="selectedLi = n">{{n}}</li>
</ul>

export class MyComponent {
  isClassVisible: false;
  num = [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

Comment: But what if I have hundreds of elements? It would be tedious to use different variable for each of them. Isn't there a more neat solution?

Comment: yeah exactly please see my Updated answer for that case

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply implementing a separate directive. To handle this click event use @HostListener and for binding the property use @HostBinding as:

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector : '[appActive]'
})
export class ActivelinkDirective{
  @HostBinding('class.active') isActive=false;

  @HostListener('click') toActive(){
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
  }
}
```

And then for the view use this directive as:

```
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item" appActive>1</li>
  <li class="item" appActive>2</li>
  <li class="item" appActive>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to have a function and only a property to set some index up to achive your goal. Your html would look like this:

```
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItemIndex == 1 }" (click)="onItemClicked(1)">1</li>
  <li class="item" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItemIndex == 2  }" (click)="onItemClicked(2)">2</li>
  <li class="item" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItemIndex == 3  }" (click)="onItemClicked(3)">3</li>
  <li class="item" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItemIndex == 4  }" (click)="onItemClicked(4)">4</li>
</ul>
```

And in your ts file:

```
public selectedItemIndex: number = 0;
onItemClicked(val: number){
  this.selectedItemIndex = val;
}
```

A plus would be to be able set the index up to its original default vale, in other words, to unselect it. One opcion would be to do it at a second click. To pull that off you would need to create a property that stores the number of clicks by index, and a timer. The timer would reset the counter to 0 after a certain amount of time, so to trigger the double click you should click it faster than the reset timer. That should be a good exercise.